# Filter out data at the end of each month using pd.Period

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas data frame and my goal is to filter out data at the end of each month (i.e. 2021-12-31, 2022-01-31, etc).

I have 2 sets of code and 1 works but the other doesn't even though they the type(criteria) is the same - string.

**Works:**

```
df_monthly = df[df.index == str(dt.date(2022,1,31))]
```

**Does not work:**

```
df_monthly = df[df.index == str(pd.Period(df.index, freq='M').end_time.date())]
```

The 2nd line returns this error:
ValueError: Value must be Period, string, integer, or datetime

Anyone knows why this is the case and how do I remedy? I'm hoping to be able to proceed using pd.Period() instead of dt.date().

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the index is a `DatetimeIndex`, you can call [`.to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html) followed by [`.to_timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Period.to_timestamp.html) on the index to do this:

```
df_monthly = df.loc[df.index == df.index.to_period('M').to_timestamp('M')]
```

If the index needs to be converted first, you can use `pd.to_datetime` (and optionally set `errors='coerce'` to handle invalid dates)

---

Another succinct option is to use [`offsets.MonthEnd`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd.html):

```
df_monthly = df.loc[df.index == df.index + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(0)]
```

Comment: Hey! The second option works! Did not try the first one.

Do you happen to know the reason why the code below does not work?
df_monthly = df[df.index == str(pd.Period(df.index, freq='M').end_time.date())]

Because both are of the same type (string) and even have the same output. It's just this one doesn't work and I'm curious to know why.

Many thanks!